# How do you make javascript keep the parameters in the URL when you have a button that reloads the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a project and I need to make it so that when my button reloads the page it does not delete the parameters in the URL.

```
if(sectionView($section)) {
                                        print "<li class='pure-menu-heading' style='cursor: pointer' onClick=\"$('li.group-$section').toggle('slow')\">$section</li>";
                                        $navItem = scandir("pages/$section");
                                        
                                        unset($navItem[0]);
                                        unset($navItem[1]);
                                foreach($navItem as $item) {
                            $pageName = substr($item, 0, -4);
                                    if(pageView($section,$pageName)) {
                                        $counter = "";
                                        if (isset($_GET['Mpage']) && $_GET['Mpage'] == substr($item, 0, -4)) $active="pure-menu-active";
                                        if($section == 'admin' || $section == 'qa') {$counter="<span class='email-count' id='menu-".substr($item, 0, -4)."' style='display:none'><label id='test' value='(".$rslt['total'].")'></label></span>";}
                                        print "<li id='".substr($item, 0, -4)."' style='display: none;'onCLick=\"window.location.reload()\" class='group-$section pure-menu-item $active'><a style='cursor: pointer' onClick=\"loadSubLinks(this,'$section', '".substr($item, 0, -4)."');\" class='pure-menu-link'>".ucfirst(str_replace('_',' ',substr($item, 0, -4)))."$counter</a></li>";
                                        $active = "";
```

The code for the button is

```
print "<li id='".substr($item, 0, -4)."' style='display: none;'onCLick=\"window.location.reload()\" class='group-$section pure-menu-item $active'><a style='cursor: pointer' onClick=\"loadSubLinks(this,'$section', '".substr($item, 0, -4)."');\" class='pure-menu-link'>".ucfirst(str_replace('_',' ',substr($item, 0, -4)))."$counter</a></li>";
```

My button is, when clicked, supposed to take the parameters from the URL which is: `http://localhost/victorphp/callvisor/bp/index.php?section=user&Mpage=tools`

But when I click the button it deletes the parameters and then reloads.

Comment: Where is the code for your button? Can't you just use `location.reload()`?

Comment: I have trieed it does the same effect

Comment: I added the code for the button and I am trying to make it so that when my page reloads the parameters are kept

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to reload page with params:

```
window.open(window.location.href,"_self")
```

`window.location.href` will fetch the current url with params,

`window.open` will load the url and `"_self"` will load the page in current tab.

Comment: When I tried this it worked but it made it so that if i do not have the parameters it would not load the page at all

Comment: Strange !, its working for me. Do you see any error in console ?

Comment: No my page has nothing it shows nothing unless the parameters are there.

Comment: If the parameters are not there the page is blank